# Creating a search service with multiple inner joins?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, web-services, inner-join

I am performing a SQL query for search restful web service . It's working fine, but I want to get the particular column names (only) to which table name like clause matches:

```
    SELECT Cou.country_id,cou.country_name, Sta.state_id, Sta.state_name, Dis.district_id,
Dis.district_name,Cit.city_id, Cit.city_name,Loc.location_id,Loc.location_name,Sub_Loc.sub_location_id,Sub_Loc.sub_location_name,Prop.property_id,Prop.property_name,Prop.hp_builders_id,
Bud.builders_id,Bud.builders_name
FROM hp_country Cou
INNER JOIN hp_state Sta ON Cou.country_id = Sta.hp_country_id
INNER JOIN hp_district Dis ON Sta.state_id = Dis.hp_state_id
INNER JOIN hp_city Cit ON Dis.district_id = Cit.hp_district_id
INNER JOIN hp_location Loc ON Cit.city_id = Loc.hp_city_id
INNER JOIN hp_sub_location Sub_Loc ON Loc.location_id = Sub_Loc.hp_location_id
INNER JOIN hp_property Prop ON Sub_Loc.sub_location_id=Prop.hp_sub_location_id
LEFT JOIN hp_builders Bud ON Prop.hp_builders_id=Bud.builders_id
where (Cou.country_status=1 AND Sta.state_status=1 AND Cou.country_id=1)    
AND (Dis.district_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Cit.city_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Loc.location_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Sub_Loc.sub_location_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Prop.property_name LIKE '%ky%')
```

I will send the parameter to above query from client to web service like search=%ky% ,so it may match to state/district/country/properties/builders,
 I am getting all the values in a particular row. Suppose if it matches in property name(skyline) its giving all the details 
 of skyline(like location,builders,city). But I want to get only matched column names of particular table.
Example:

1. row property name(skyline),property id(1)
2. row builders name(skyline),builders id(9)
3. row location name(skill india),location id(10)